# Correct ( safe ) way to loop through POST variables in PHP

Tags: php, post, jqgrid

I have some legacy code which I want to update.  In that version of the code ( which was a backend for jqGrid ), the search parameters where sent to the server in the POST variables.  The POST key is the field name, and the value is the search value.  Starting a few years ago I started only accessing POST variables via the `filter_input` function, which was suggested by my IDE.  However I haven't found a recommended way to loop through the POST variables without accessing the POST variable directly.

The portion of the legacy code for search parameters is like this:

```
/*
 * Search Filter
 */
if ($search){
    $where_string = ' where ';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        if (in_array($key,array('_search','nd','rows','page','sidx','sord','arg1','arg2'))==true){
            continue;
        }
        //put in functionality to search for exact values
        //to search for exact values, include a * character before the value you are searching for
        if (strpos($value, "*") === 0){
            //exact search
            $value = substr($value,1);
        }else{
            //like search
            $value = "%".$value."%";
        }
        $key = $mysqli->real_escape_string($key);
        $value = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
        $where_string .= '`'.$key.'` like "'.$value.'" AND ';
    }
    $where_string = rtrim($where_string,' AND ');
}
```

The warning that my IDE gives is: `Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly.`
 on the `foreach` line.  Just not sure if I am supposed to avoid this kind of loop completely, or if there is a way to use filter_input with that.  It is kind of a generic code for any table. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: You can access data in $_POST directly and safely if you know what you are doing and take some precautions to filter and escape the data and whatnot. If you're not porting your code to some framework which does the work for you, you should look into ways of sanitizing the data and you can remain using the current foreach loop safely

Comment: I'm curious, which IDE do you use?

Comment: Even if you first tried to get all the keys with `array_keys($_POST)`, that would be using $_POST directly as well. Its a very limiting warning for sure. Without actually knowing all possible keys beforehand, you are going to have to ignore that warning and do what you must. If you can setup some sort of whitelist array of keys, you can at least limit what gets tossed into your sql, and have a level of assurance that no one passes in keys you are not expecting.

Comment: i suspect that warning relates to using POST variables directly in SQL statements. Netbeans gives this warning for that very reason. It doesn't mean that accessing POST variables directly is inherently dangerous.

Comment: If you're operating at a low level like this, you're going to have to interact with superglobals directly. Potentially you could have a white-list of keys and try each of them in turn, I guess? For reference, Symfony's HTTP foundation component (which is fairly ubiquitous at this point) accesses all of PHP's superglobals directly when the Request object is being initialised.

Comment: @FergalAndrews yes its NetBeans.  OK thanks for the input.  Seems logical that at some point we need to interact directly with the POST variable in this case.